# Output of Batch file with a number of cmd commands saved in a single text file

Tags: text, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get the output of my batch file into a text file. I know by using '>'
I can get the standard output stream text, however in this case the batch file has multiple cmd commands and I don't know how to get outputs for each of this into a text file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
@echo off
rem start the file with a single >
echo test1 > file.txt
rem append the file with a double >>
echo test2 >> file.txt
type file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. So by using pipe I should be able to it.

Comment: The >> is a double greater than sign, the pipe is this | but William's answer will work perfectly.